# Methods to trigger a gallery/music player refresh?

Tags: sd-card, music-player, gallery, stock-android

I've search around the internet for details regarding this, and the only way I found was to remount the SD card..

But I have a lot of apps (virtually, all) installed on my SDcard and this is probably what is causing me enormous time to unmount and remount the sd card. Furthermore, just unmounting the sdcard itself takes almost an eternity. (I dont know if this is a bug or if its due to my large no of apps; i have around 90 apps).. So this method is really inconvenient for me

So I wanted to know if there are other methods to refresh my gallery items and music player. Is there any small app that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't been asking the right question in your research.

Have you tried searching 'rescan media' in the android market? A multitude of apps will be returned.

Personally the great app Widgetsoid has this function amongst a multitude of options/settings.

Answer (score 1):

To refresh the list of your music you do following:

Go into settings->manage apps->ALL services. Scroll down and select "Media Storage." Then hit the "Clear Data" icon.

Source: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-4-general-discussion/220965-players-dont-detect-music-my-sd-card-after-ics-update.html

Comment: Good to know from the same source: `You must then reboot your phone, and at boot the phone runs the media update service in the background. It could take up to an hour for this database to be populated and updated. At that point, you'll see your music again in your players, and your photos and movies in the gallery.`